# How to make gdalbuildvrt available in processing modeller?

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing

I would like to make a model in QGIS that builds a virtualraster from several raster files. Unfortunately the gdal function is not available on the modeller. So, my question is: how to make this function available? It is necessary to construct a python script? If so how can I indicate the several raster files?
Thanks.

Comment: A few GDAL algorithms were added today.This link may help with that:http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/repository/revisions/4512bfcb4482655f8f90d37bd58f5a4dded193f7

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm using the QGIS 2.0.1 and I don't know how to update the processing tools.